# jQuery Slideshow not working in IE8, works fine in Safari/Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, slideshow

The website (www.hilaryandmatthew.com) for my upcoming wedding has a really nifty JQuery slideshow (courtesy of www.dynamicdrive.com)

I hope I can get some help ASAP, I really want my site looking sharp before I send out the Invitations.  I don't know anything about jQuery. Hence I experience the pitfall of copy&pasting open-source code.

I am getting this error when I try to load the page in IE8:

---

Message: 'imagearray[...].0' is null or not an object
Line: 39
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://www.hilaryandmatthew.com/includes/slideshow/fadeslideshow.js

---

This is the code with my image array that passes into the function 'fadeSlideShow(settingarg)'

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
    wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [267, 200], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
    imagearray: [
                ["images/ss1.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss2.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss3.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss4.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss5.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss6.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss7.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss9.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss10.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss11.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss12.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss13.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss14.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss15.jpg", "", "", ""],

        ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:2800, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
    persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    fadeduration: 600, //transition duration (milliseconds)
    descreveal: "ondemand",
    togglerid: ""
})
</script>
```

Here is the code with the error in a separate .js file:

```
var fadeSlideShow_descpanel={
    controls: [['/includes/slideshow/x.png',7,7], ['/includes/slideshow/restore.png',10,11], ['/includes/slideshow/loading.gif',54,55]], 

//full URL and dimensions of close, restore, and loading images

fontStyle: 'normal 12px Verdana', //font style for text descriptions
slidespeed: 200 //speed of description panel animation (in millisec)
}

//No need to edit beyond here...

jQuery.noConflict()

function fadeSlideShow(settingarg){

    this.setting=settingarg
    settingarg=null
    var setting=this.setting
    setting.fadeduration=setting.fadeduration? parseInt(setting.fadeduration) : 500
    setting.curimage=(setting.persist)? fadeSlideShow.routines.getCookie("gallery-"+setting.wrapperid) : 0
    setting.curimage=setting.curimage || 0 //account for curimage being null if cookie is empty
    setting.currentstep=0 //keep track of # of slides slideshow has gone through (applicable in displaymode='auto' only)
    setting.totalsteps=setting.imagearray.length*(setting.displaymode.cycles>0? setting.displaymode.cycles : Infinity) //Total steps limit (applicable in displaymode='auto' only w/ cycles>0)
    setting.fglayer=0, setting.bglayer=1 //index of active and background layer (switches after each change of slide)
    setting.displaymode.randomize=true
        setting.oninit=setting.oninit || function(){}
    setting.onslide=setting.onslide || function(){}
    if (setting.displaymode.randomize) //randomly shuffle order of images?
        setting.imagearray.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()})
    var preloadimages=[] //preload images
    setting.longestdesc="" //get longest description of all slides. If no desciptions defined, variable contains ""
    for (var i=0; i<setting.imagearray.length; i++){ //preload images
        preloadimages[i]=new Image()
```

-LINE 39, SOURCE OF ERRROR, BELOW -

```
 preloadimages[i].src=setting.imagearray[i][0]

                if (setting.imagearray[i][3] && setting.imagearray[i]

[3].length>setting.longestdesc.length)
                setting.longestdesc=setting.imagearray[i][3]
        }
        var closebutt=fadeSlideShow_descpanel.controls[0] //add close button to "desc" panel if descreveal="always"
        setting.closebutton=(setting.descreveal=="always")? '<img class="close" src="'+closebutt[0]+'" style="float:right;cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;width:'+closebutt[1]+'px;height:'+closebutt[2]+'px;margin-left:2px" title="Hide Description" />' : ''
        var slideshow=this
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //fire on DOM ready
            var setting=slideshow.setting
            var fullhtml=fadeSlideShow.routines.getFullHTML(setting.imagearray) //get full HTML of entire slideshow
            setting.$wrapperdiv=$('#'+setting.wrapperid).css({position:'relative', visibility:'visible', background:'black', overflow:'hidden', width:setting.dimensions[0], height:setting.dimensions[1]}).empty() //main slideshow DIV
            if (setting.$wrapperdiv.length==0){ //if no wrapper DIV found
                alert("Error: DIV with ID \""+setting.wrapperid+"\" not found on page.")
                return
            }
            setting.$gallerylayers=$('<div class="gallerylayer"></div><div class="gallerylayer"></div>') //two stacked DIVs to display the actual slide
                .css({position:'absolute', left:0, top:0, width:'100%', height:'100%', background:'black'})
                .appendTo(setting.$wrapperdiv)
            var $loadingimg=$('<img src="'+fadeSlideShow_descpanel.controls[2][0]+'" style="position:absolute;width:'+fadeSlideShow_descpanel.controls[2][1]+';height:'+fadeSlideShow_descpanel.controls[2][2]+'" />')
                .css({left:setting.dimensions[0]/2-fadeSlideShow_descpanel.controls[2][1]/2, top:setting.dimensions[1]/2-fadeSlideShow_descpanel.controls[2][2]}) //center loading gif
                .appendTo(setting.$wrapperdiv)
            var $curimage=setting.$gallerylayers.html(fullhtml).find('img').hide().eq(setting.curimage) //prefill both layers with entire slideshow content, hide all images, and return current image
            if (setting.longestdesc!=""){ //if at least one slide contains a description (feature is enabled)
                fadeSlideShow.routines.adddescpanel($, setting)
                if (setting.descreveal=="always"){ //position desc panel so it's visible to begin with
                    setting.$descpanel.css({top:setting.dimensions[1]-setting.panelheight})
                    setting.$descinner.click(function(e){ //asign click behavior to "close" icon
                        if (e.target.className=="close"){
                            slideshow.showhidedescpanel('hide')
                        }
                    })
                    setting.$restorebutton.click(function(e){ //asign click behavior to "restore" icon
                        slideshow.showhidedescpanel('show')
                        $(this).css({visibility:'hidden'})
                    })
                }
                else{ //display desc panel on demand (mouseover)
                    setting.$wrapperdiv.bind('mouseenter', function(){slideshow.showhidedescpanel('show')})
                    setting.$wrapperdiv.bind('mouseleave', function(){slideshow.showhidedescpanel('hide')})
                }
            }
            setting.$wrapperdiv.bind('mouseenter', function(){setting.ismouseover=true}) //pause slideshow mouseover
            setting.$wrapperdiv.bind('mouseleave', function(){setting.ismouseover=false})
            if ($curimage.get(0).complete){ //accounf for IE not firing image.onload
                $loadingimg.hide()
                slideshow.paginateinit($)
                slideshow.showslide(setting.curimage)
            }
            else{ //initialize slideshow when first image has fully loaded
                $loadingimg.hide()
                slideshow.paginateinit($)
                $curimage.bind('load', function(){slideshow.showslide(setting.curimage)})
            }
            setting.oninit.call(slideshow) //trigger oninit() event
            $(window).bind('unload', function(){ //clean up and persist
                if (slideshow.setting.persist) //remember last shown image's index
                    fadeSlideShow.routines.setCookie("gallery-"+setting.wrapperid, setting.curimage)
                jQuery.each(slideshow.setting, function(k){
                    if (slideshow.setting[k] instanceof Array){
                        for (var i=0; i<slideshow.setting[k].length; i++){
                            if (slideshow.setting[k][i].tagName=="DIV") //catches 2 gallerylayer divs, gallerystatus div
                                slideshow.setting[k][i].innerHTML=null
                            slideshow.setting[k][i]=null
                        }
                    }
                })
                slideshow=slideshow.setting=null
            })
        })
    }
```

There are a few more functions in the file.. if they are relevant, the full source is available at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to clarify further, I personally spend some time finding it...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
    wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [267, 200], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
    imagearray: [
                ["images/ss1.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss2.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss3.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss4.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss5.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss6.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss7.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss9.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss10.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss11.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss12.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss13.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss14.jpg", "", "", ""],
                ["images/ss15.jpg", "", "", ""],   <<==== Delete this comma

        ],
```

Answer (score 4):

the issue is directly in the first block of code you posted: Internet Explorer doesn't like trailing commas in objects and arrays.
You just need to remove the trailing comma from the last element in `imagearray` and it should work (if it doesn't, check other arrays and objects for the same issue)